# How can I create a slider using Websharper?

Tags: f#, websharper

I'm just learning Websharper so I'm still quite confused.

On the Intellifactory samples webpage the code for the calculator sample seems to use `Button` as if Webshaper provides some GUI controls but the code installed on disk uses its own helper function to create a button like this:

```
let btn caption action =
  Input [Attr.Type "button"; Attr.Value caption; Attr.Style "width: 30px"]
  |>! OnClick (fun e _ -> action ())
```

as if Webshaper does not include basic GUI controls so you must do things like this to obtain them (which seems to defeat the purpose of using an abstraction like Websharper).

I want a slider with a callback that is invoked whenever its value changes. How can I get one using Websharper?

Answer (score 4):

you can use slider from JQueryUI:

```
[<JavaScript>]
override this.Body = 
    let text = Span []
    let slider = Slider.New(SliderConfiguration(min = 0, max = 10, value = 5))
    // typed way to subscribe doesn't work, internally tries to bind handler to 'sliderslide' event
    // per documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) should be 'slide'
    // slider.OnSlide(fun _ -> text.Text <- string slider.Value ) 
    JQuery.JQuery.Of(slider.Widget).Bind("slide", Func<_, _, _>(fun _ _ -> text.Text <- string slider.Value )).Ignore
    Div [
        Div [ slider ]
        Div [ text ]
    ] :> _
```

Comment: There is also our library that attempts to add a little more typing to the JQuery UI code. You can obtain the latest from NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/WebSharper.JQueryUi